# How to prevent someone from copying and redistributing your osx app

Tags: swift, macos, resources, bundle, copying

I have written a completely stand-alone OSX app (in Swift 5). The app collects no data. Is not connected to any backend server. It is a utility app where all user data is saved on the user's device.

How do I prevent someone from copying and redistributing the app. For example, a customer pays for the app and downloads it. They then copy the app and send it to 10 of their friends. Now 10 people have the app who did not purchase it.  I have tested this and the app can be sent to anyone. It works just fine.

One solution was to capture the Mac Address of the user's device and save this within a file on the Apps Bundle. However, Apple does not allow writing to the Apps Bundle. Plus it invalidates the signature.

If I can just write some data to a file somewhere, that stays within the App, that would be perfect.

How do App Developers prevent malicious redistribution of a stand-alone application?

Comment: Roughly speaking, you can’t. Any activation/license scheme you try to build in could also be just be modded out. See all the cracks for Windows and Adobe products, for example.

Comment: With a license the user must at least go out and actively search for a cracked version or a copy of the license key so they are aware that they are stealing the software. Without any type of license they might believe it is free, so even if anything can be cracked at least the honest users will pay for the app if it has a license.

Comment: @Alexander, You are right. But I'm just trying to stop the majority of "illegal" redistribution. It doesn't need to be a fully encrypted licensing scheme. Just something that will prevent the majority.

Comment: Can you sell your app via Apple's App Store? If so, you can [validate the receipt from that](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html) in your app.

Comment: As other developers do you can create a file inside the application support folder and provide a kind of authentication service but IMO it doesn't worth all this trouble specially if the app price is low.

Comment: @GordonDavisson This is a great find and I believe it will accomplish what I am looking for. I will implement, test, and update this post with results as soon as I can. Thank you!

Comment: @LeoDabus Unfortunately, the Application Support folder is within the App's container (App's Sandbox) on the user's device. When you copy the app itself, the sandbox folders are not copied with it.